# Looking for the name of an obscure percussion instrument

Tags: percussion

I'm trying to find out what an instrument is called. Please tell me I'm not crazy because everyone I ask looks at me like I'm from outer space.

I saw it years ago in my friend's cymbal catalog, either Zildjian or Paiste, I can't remember. I only saw a photo so I don't know how big it is but it looked fairly small, maybe six inches across. It's made of a solid piece of flat brass. It has an irregular, but symmetrical curving shape with a small hole at the top.

The way my friend explained, it would hang by a string and you would spin it and strike it, or make it spin by striking it. I imagine it would sound something like a crotale except with a shimmering sound.

Even the friend that showed it to me doesn't seem to know what I'm talking about.

---

Edit: I have found a photo of the instrument in question. It is from a 1988 Zildjian catalog I found [here](http://www.vintagecymbalguide.com/zildjian_literature.html). Unfortunately it is super low-res. If the resolution were higher I would have my answer from the text of the catalog. At least you can make out the general shape and see that it is hanging from a stand.

[image]

I am not sure if my description of how it is played or how it sounds is accurate. At least now I know I didn't imagine it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a Burma Bell.

[image: Burma Bell]

[image]

Here's the full resolution page of the catalog: 
http://www.vintagecymbalguide.com/images/literature/zildjian/zildjian_catalog_2-12.jpg

And this is how it sounds:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epHHvPEjjMM

Answer (score 1):

From physical description and the sound you imagine it makes, seems like you're talking about a [Hang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_%28instrument%29), but a hang isn't hung by a string.

Comment: No.that's not it.